# How to model in Enterprise Architect a hardware-dependent file such as iom8.h

Tags: uml, header-files, enterprise-architect

I'm currently trying to make a small project in EA in order to get used to it. I'm trying to togglea LED of an ATMEGA8.

I've modelled my system but as you may know, there's a .h file for each kind of microcontroller with the pin definitions. It looks like this:

```
SFR_B(TWBR prm1, 0x00 prm2);
SFR_B(TWSR prm1, 0X01 prm2);
SFR_B(TWAR prm1, 0x02 prm2);
SFR_B(TWDR prm1, 0x03 prm2);
SFR_B(ADCSR prm1, 0x06 prm2);
SFR_B(ADMUX prm1, 0x07 prm2);
SFR_B(ACSR prm1, 0x08 prm2);
SFR_B(UBRRL prm1, 0x09 prm2);
SFR_B(UCSRB prm1, 0x0A prm2);
SFR_B(UCSRA prm1, 0x0B prm2);
SFR_B(UDR prm1, 0x0C prm2);
SFR_B(SPCR prm1, 0x0D prm2);
SFR_B(SPSR prm1, 0x0E prm2);
SFR_B(SPDR prm1, 0x0F prm2);
SFR_B(PIND prm1, 0x10 prm2);
SFR_B(DDRD prm1, 0x11 prm2);
SFR_B(PORTD prm1, 0x12 prm2);
...
```

How could I model this in EA, so when I generate the code, this file is also included?

Thanks in advance.